# PHP+Apache losing the session

Tags: php, apache2, session-cookies

I have a PHP application which loses the session after a while on a LAMP VPS I share with some collegues.

The same application doesn't have this problem on my local MAMP server.

I have had the same problem in the past with the same VPS, but I can't recall how (or even *if*) I fixed it, and I have no idea about what could be causing this. I've played around with the cookie params but it didn't help.

I start it this way:

```
session_name($COOKIE_NAME);
session_set_cookie_params($COOKIE_LIFE,$COOKIE_PATH,$COOKIE_DOMAIN);
session_start();
```

The `path` is set to "/" on both occasions, the domain is set on `xxx.localhost:8888` on my MAMP and `xxx.mydomain.net` on the VPS, and the life is the same for both servers.

I've also tried with an empty `domain` parameter, since this in past fixed a similar problem, but nothing changed: it still worked locally and was broken on the VPS.

Does anyone have any idea on where could I investigate to find this problem?

Comment: Have you checked session.cookie_lifetime in the php.ini?

Comment: @juco calling `session_get_cookie_params()` returns the correct value.

Comment: checking the `session_save_path()` was a nice tip, lucky I've been able to read it before it was deleted... why was it deleted? I'm trying it now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I had the same problem highlighted in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251550/php-resetting-session-after-some-time), and solved it the same way.

Comment: Thanks to the guy who hinted about `session_save_path()` in the comments, and I'm still quite puzzled about why did he delete that comment a few minutes after writing it, and I feel lucky I managed to read it before that.